# Sugarcrm : How to rewrite a document URL

Tags: templates, url, customization, sugarcrm

**My version :**

SugarCRM CE 6.5.2 running on linux

**What I want to do :**

I've customized the Documents module in "custom/modules/Documents" by writing several logic hooks.
These logic hooks creates new folders in "ressources/" which is my new upload folder. (I've change the 'upload_dir' from "./upload" into "./ressources" in the config.php)
This is done through a custom field created in studio named "folder_name"
And then, the logic hooks cut and paste the document uploaded into this new folder.

**What is my problem**

So, with all of this, my download url in Edit, Detail and Revisions Subpanel Views is false. I would like to change it to the right folder, like, for example adding a folder parameter in the url
like this :

/index.php?entryPoint=download&folder=Images&id=idDoc&type=Documents

I tried to change the a href link in EditView.tpl or DetailView.tpl, (like )
but it didn't work since they were located in my cache/modules/Documents folder and were overriding when i did a quick repair.

So I copies/pasted the DetailView.tpl and the EditView.tpl into custom/modules/Documents/tpls and tried to override the view.edit.php and the view.detail.php to link the customized templates, but it did not work. 
code :

```
<?php

  require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.detail.php');

  class DocumentsViewDetail extends ViewDetail {

     function DocumentsViewDetail() {
       parent::ViewDetail();
     }

    function display() {
      parent::display();
    }

    function detailViewProcess() {
      $this->processSearchForm();
      $this->lv->searchColumns = $this->searchForm->searchColumns;

      if (!$this->headers)
        return;
      if (empty($_REQUEST['search_form_only']) || $_REQUEST['search_form_only'] == false) {
        //here we are overriding with your custom template            
        $this->lv->setup($this->seed, 'custom/modules/Documents/tpls/DetailView.tpl', $this->where, $this->params);
        echo $this->lv->display();
       }
   }

}

?>
```

Do you have any idea why this doesn't work?

Do you have any idea on how i could rewrite my URLS or override the Edit, Revisions SubPanel and Details Views?

Please answer, this is **URGENT**

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the folder parameter to the variable `$file_url` inside the method `fill_in_additional_detail_fields()` in `modules/Documents/Document.php`.

[Edited]

`EditView: include/SugarFields/Fields/File/EditView.tpl`
`DetailView: include/SugarFields/Fields/File/DetailView.tpl`

`<a href="index.php?entryPoint=download&id={$fields.{{$vardef.fileId}}.value}&type={{$vardef.linkModule}}&folder=test" ...`

`ListView: include/SugarFields/Fields/File/ListView.tpl`

`<a href="index.php?entryPoint=download&id={$parentFieldArray.ID}&type={$displayParams.module}{$vardef.displayParams.module}&folder=test" ...`

Comment: Hi, @air4x! First, thanks for your answer! I tried what you said by changing the $file_url in **modules/Documents/Document.php** AND in **custom/modules/Documents/Document.php** by just writing the url by hand :    <a href="ressources/{$this->folder_name_c}/{$this->document_revision_id}">

**AND** I changed the $query to take my documents_cstm.folder_name_c and my documents.id . of course.
But it did not change anything.. do you have another idea?

Comment: @Gaelle Try changing `$this->file_url_noimage` too. Also, I don't think copying `Document.php` to `custom/modules/Documents/Document.php` will work.

Comment: i saw on sugarcrm documentation that writing all your changes in custom folder is the way to have an upgrade-safe code... So i prefer to write my modifications here. It worked for my logic hooks, so i think it would work for the rest, but i have to find a way to override the views.
and $this->file_url_noimage, well, i don't know what it does, and i thought it had not much to do with my url rewriting... i am totally lost, so if someone has an idea...

Comment: @Gaelle `$this->file_url_noimage` is present in `fill_in_additional_detail_fields()`. It would be `$this->file_url_noimage = "index.php?entryPoint=download&type=Documents&id={$this->document_revision_id}";` now. try adding your folder parameter to it and see if it works.

Comment: i got this : `$this->file_url_noimage = "index.php?entryPoint=download&folder={$this->folder_name_c}&type=Documents&id={$this->document_revision_id}";`
and this: `$file_url = "<a href='index.php?entryPoint=download&folder={$this->folder_name_c}&id={$this->document_revision_id}&type=Documents' target='_blank'>".SugarThemeRegistry::current()->getImage($img_name, 'border="0"', null,null,'.gif',$mod_strings['LBL_LIST_VIEW_DOCUMENT'])."</a>";`
and it doesn't work. Why does the file_url_noimage has something to do with my document url? could you explian to me please?

Comment: yes, but only for the Documents module. I tried to modify directly the download.php file... without success

Comment: @Gaelle Edit the `tpl` files in `include/SugarFields/Fields/File/`. Modifying it seems to work.

Comment: i'm sorry, could you show me your code, because i made `{{if $vardef.linkModule = 'Documents'}}
<a href="index.php?entryPoint=download&folder={$fields.{{$vardef.folder}}&id={$fields.{{$vardef.fileId}}.value}&type={{$vardef.linkModule}}" class="tabDetailViewDFLink" target='_blank'>{{sugarvar key='value'}}</a>
{{else}}//write normal link` and it just broke my DetailView (see here : [link](http://tinyurl.com/bnv7fa4)

Comment: in fact, where do you build the $vardef? because i don't know, but maybe it broke my code, because didn't find it...

Comment: @Gaelle if you have a custom field in `Documents` named `folder_name` try `{$fields.folder_name.value}`. i tried using the name field and it worked i.e. `{$fields.name.value}`

Comment: it seems to work (even if it appears not stable), i think i'll have to do some modifications, and i'll come back to you if i have another troubles. Thanks a lot, you saved my day! :)

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @air4x, i did answer my trouble : overriding the DetailView.tpl
To make it upgrade-safe, i copies it from

```
include/SugarFields/Fields/File/DetailView.tpl
```

to

```
custom/include/SugarFields/Fields/File/DetailView.tpl
```

It works!

**BUT there is a big trouble coming...**

explanations :
1] I create a new Document, uploading image01 to Folder01. Save. Database ok. in DetailView the folder name is "Folder01" and the link '//Folder01/image01_id' works.

2] I create another new Document, uploading image02 to Folder02. Save. Databse ok. BUT in DetailView the folder's name is not "Folder02" but "Folder01". AND the link is //Folder01/image02_id so it doesn't work, because in database or in my folders, the file is still in Folder02.

Here is my custom/include/SugarFields/Fields/File/DetailView.tpl code :

```
//BEGIN the code i modified
<span class="sugar_field" id="{{if empty($displayParams.idName)}}{{sugarvar key='name'}}{{else}}{{$displayParams.idName}}{{/if}}">
   <a href="ressources/{$fields.folder_name_c.value}/{$fields.{{$vardef.fileId}}.value}" class="tabDetailViewDFLink" target='_blank'>{{sugarvar key='value'}}</a>
</span>
//END the code i modified

{{if isset($vardef) && isset($vardef.allowEapm) && $vardef.allowEapm}}
    {if isset($fields.{{$vardef.docType}}) && !empty($fields.{{$vardef.docType}}.value) && $fields.{{$vardef.docType}}.value != 'SugarCRM' && !empty($fields.{{$vardef.docUrl}}.value) }
        {capture name=imageNameCapture assign=imageName}
          {$fields.{{$vardef.docType}}.value}_image_inline.png
        {/capture}
        <a href="{$fields.{{$vardef.docUrl}}.value}" class="tabDetailViewDFLink" target="_blank">{sugar_getimage name=$imageName alt=$imageName other_attributes='border="0" '}</a>
   {/if}
{{/if}}
{{if !empty($displayParams.enableConnectors)}}
    {{sugarvar_connector view='DetailView'}}
{{/if}}
```

I really don't know why my **$fields.folder_name_c.value** stay from the first document and replace the one in the second document...
Do you know how i could do a sql query in my EditView.tpl to change it and have the right value?

Please, i really need help.

Thank you

(ps : @air4x, thanks a LOT, even if i have another trouble, that showed me hox to override EditView. **THANK YOU!** )

Comment: I am not sure, but try adding double braces i.e. `{{$fields.folder_name_c.value}}`. I think it would keep it as a parameter for smarty to parse in the cached template file.

Comment: I tried : it doesn't find the variable.
i've got `<a href="ressources/{{$fields.folder_name_c.value}}/{$fields.{{$vardef.fileId}}.value}"...>`
and the url says `ressources//DocID` because it's empty, i believe it did not find the good name. I'm now in week end but i'll try to come tomorrow and after to check and try to got the code. Thanks for trying to help me @air4x